# How to make delete button an html button instead of an ajax button

Tags: javascript, html, ajax, asp.net-core

I want to change the delete button from an ajax button to an html button. I am currently using ajax/javascript for the delete button. When I click the Delete button, a modal window to confirm that I want to delete comes up and once I click confirm it will delete the vote. The Delete Action redirect I changed to RedirectToAction but the page errors out (InvalidOperationException: No route matches the supplied values.).  The redirect isn't right I believe or maybe I need another return for the method?

```
  <div class="modal fade" id="delete-vote-modal" tabindex="-1" 
   role="dialog" 
 data-backdrop="static">
  <form method="post" asp-controller="Discussion" asp-action="DeleteVote" 
     enctype="multipart/form-data">
    <input id="packet-item-id" asp-for="@Model.PacketItemId" type="hidden" 
      />
        <input id="voting-type" asp-for="@Model.VotingType" type="hidden" 
     />
     <div class="modal-dialog">
         <div class="modal-content">
            <div class="modal-header">
                <h5 class="modal-title">Delete Vote</h5>
                <button type="button" class="close" data-dismiss="modal" 
      aria-label="Close">
                    <span aria-hidden="true">&times;</span>
                </button>
            </div>
            <div class="modal-body">
                <input type="hidden" name="voteId" id="voteId" value="" />
                Do you want to delete this vote ?
                <div style="text-align: center; display: none" 
            id="loaderDiv">
                    <img src="~/images/loading.gif" width="150" />
                </div>
            </div>
            <div class="modal-footer">
                <a href="#" class="btn btn-default" data- 
              dismiss="modal">Cancel</a>
                <input type="submit"
                       value="Confirm"
                       class="btn btn-success col-sm-12 col-md-2 col-lg-2"
                       data-action="submit" />
                
               </div>
           </div>
        </div>
   </form>
```

```
[HttpPost]
    public async Task<IActionResult> DeleteVote(long voteId, int 
    packetItemId, string votingType, CancellationToken cancellationToken)
     {
        try
        {
            await _discussionService.DeleteVoteAsync(
                    voteId,
                    cancellationToken)
                .ConfigureAwait(true);
            TempData.Put(key: TempDataKey.Vote.DeleteMessage,
                
  StatusMessageModel.Create(UserStringsService.VoteDeletedSuccessfully, 
  false));
            return RedirectToAction("/Vote?packetItemId=" + packetItemId + 
    "&votingType=" + votingType);
            //return Json(new { isSuccess = true, statusMessage = 
   UserStringsService.VoteDeletedSuccessfully });
        }
        catch
        {
            Logger.LogError($"Error in deleting the Vote Id: {voteId}");
            TempData.Put(key: TempDataKey.Vote.DeleteMessage,                    
    StatusMessageModel.Create(UserStringsService.VoteDeleteFailed, false));
            return RedirectToAction("/Discussion/Vote?packetItemId=" + 
   packetItemId + "&votingType=" + votingType);
              //return Json(new { isSuccess = false, statusMessage = 
  UserStringsService.VoteDeleteFailed });
        }
      }
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

From the code, the bakend need to receive the data with an object.

Note: the route parameter in Redirect is an absolute path.

```
   [HttpPost]
    public async Task<IActionResult> DeleteVote(ViewModel viewModel, CancellationToken cancellationToken)
    {
        return Redirect("/Discussion/Vote?packetItemId="+viewModel.PacketItemId+ "&votingType="+viewModel.VotingType);
    }
    public IActionResult Vote(int packetItemId, string votingType)
    {
        return Ok(new { packetItemId = packetItemId, votingType = votingType });
    }
```

Model

```
public class ViewModel
{

    public int PacketItemId { get; set; }
    public string VotingType { get; set; }
    //...
}
```

Comment: I tried this and it just submits the form as if I casted another vote instead of deleting the vote. I need to delete the vote. It acts like the vote button does.

Comment: You want to remove the vote module? You could have many vote card, so you can pass a object to find the node, then remove the element (vote).

Comment: @bootsy, this could help you delete the element.

Comment: I don't want ajax at all. I want to use html and no ajax used at all.

Comment: Yes, you can remove all ajax and redirect through bakend.

Comment: Hi @Karney I hope you are still around. This works but my only problem is on the redirect in the controller. I'm not sure what needs to go in there. I can't have those hard coded values in there. Do I need to pass packetitemId and votingType?

Comment: @bootsy, you can get `packetItemId` and `votingType` from the view, please refer to the edited code.

Comment: Hey @Karney, thanks for this. This worked but I think I might just need to make this a link button or button without the modal window. So just clicking delete to delete the vote without the modal window or if there is a way to use the modal window without any javascript and just go straight to the method action in the controller. Does that make sense?

Comment: @bootsy, I have edited the answer,  `packetItemId` and `votingType` need to be passed in from the backend.

Comment: Hi @Karney, sorry to bother you again but I had to make a change to my original post. I got rid of the javascript completely out of necessity. I know am using a form action to submit the delete vote for the Confirm button. The problem is when I debug by clicking Confirm button it doesn't even hit the DeleteVote action based on the code I have. What am I doing wrong here?

Comment: Look at my original post @Karney for an update to my comment above. Thanks

Comment: @bootsy, you're welcome, you need to  change the parameter as an object (FromForm) in the bakend.